# Invoking `call()` on function doesn't pass `this` argument with promises

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, node-modules

Have a problem trying to pass an object as context from one module to the next:

this is how my flow should work and i think i'm missing something or just woke up dumb today :D

```
module.exports = dixell = { // Dixell lib 
   fns: {
    slaveType: async (adr) => {
      let type;
      try {
        client.setID(adr);
        type = await client.readHoldingRegisters(1,2);
        let mswordMsbyte = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(type.data[0].toString(2).slice(0,-8), 2));
        let lswordCode = parseInt(registers.data[1].toString(2).slice(0,-6), 2);
        return `${mswordMsbyte}${lswordCode}`;
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

^^ 1st module holds the function. to this function i try to bind an object as `this` by invoking it on another module with `call()`

```
const ModbusRTU = require('modbus-serial');
const client = new ModbusRTU(); // this creates the object i want to pass
const dixell = require('../../libraries/dixell');
// sleep function 
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

client.connectRTUBuffered('COM3', { baudRate: 9600 }); 

module.exports = exports = {} 

exports.plcQueueFns = async (adr, fns) => {
  let data = {};
  for(let fn of fns) {
    console.log(typeof(client))
    data[fn.key] = await fn.fn(adr);
    await sleep(10);
  }
  return data;
}

exports.getPayload = async (plantid) => {
  let adrs = await exports.getPlcs();
  let devices = [];
  for (let adr of adrs) {
    try {
      let fnsdata = await exports.plcQueueFns(adr, [
        {key: 'type', fn: dixell.fns.slaveType},
      ]);
  }
}
```

^^ on the 2nd module i have a function called `getPayload` that starts a loop and runs other functions in a loop with `plcQueueFns`

but i can't get to pass context 
i've tried :

in `getPaylod` to send the function like this

`{key: 'type', fn: dixell.fns.slaveType.bind(client)}` > not working

i also tried in `plcQueueFns` to invoke it with

`data[fn.key] = await fn.fn.call(client, adr)` > Still nothing

in `slaveType()` i get `{}` for `this`

and this error comes up

`ReferenceError: client is not defined`

Please advice . what am i doing wrong or missing ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Arrow functions use lexically-scoped this and ignore the callsite.

Comment: so basically just writing instead of arrow function a regular one will fix the issue?

Comment: Your `slaveType` function doesn't even use `this` anywhere? And while you could make that work, it's probably easier to just declare `client` as a parameter.

Comment: That's correct. You can't change the `this` binding of an arrow function.

Comment: @Barmar i didn't know thank for clearing this up i will read about this a bit more.

Comment: @bergi i know it would be easier i just wanted to separate logic .. probably will be easier . thanks for your input every body. 

if any one want to explain a bit about lexically-scoped as an aswer i will accept it ..